# Why the digit Sum of a non negative number(n) is always the remainder after division by 9 , until n becomes only one digit?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

lets assume for  $689$ : ,

> $$689 = (6+ 8 + 9 ) = 23$$
> $$23 = (2 + 3) = 5$$

We can get this way:
$$689 \!\!\mod \;9 = 5$$

I found a approach like this:
$$10 = (9 * 1) + 1 $$
$$100 = (9 * 11) + 1 $$

this way :
$$689 = 9 + (8*10) + (6*100)$$
$$689 = 9 + (8*(9+1)) + (6*(9 * 11 + 1))$$
$$689 = (9+8+6) + 9 * ((8 * 1) + (6 * 11))$$

But I couldn't figure out out how to proceed forward after this?

Comment: The number you get at the end (in this case, $5$), is called the *digital root*. For example, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221486/a-pedagogical-proof-that-9s-can-be-ignored-when-calculating-digital-roots) similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Hint) :- Use modular arithmetic .

Note that $10^n \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$ for any positive integer $n$ and every number can be uniquely represented as $10^na_1 + 10^{n - 1}a_2 + ... + a_n$ where $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are positive integers from the set $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$ .

You have actually done the same thing in the case of $689$ . Since you got :-
$$(9 + 8 + 6) + 9 * ((8*1) + (6*11))$$
We get :- $689 \equiv (9 + 8 + 6)\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$

=> $(9 + 8 + 6) \equiv 5\ (\textrm{mod}\ 9)$
, and that's the same dealing with the remainder of the sum of digits after division by $9$ .

**Edit :-** As mentioned by @Toby Mak, the remainder found from the division by $9$ is called it's digital root .