# A property of digital sum

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

I was working on a computer program and came up with an intuitive idea that reduces the program module by a considerable length. The idea is intuitive but I never came up with a proof.

**Claim:** For a natural number $ n $, let $ S ( n ) $ denote the sum of digits of $ n $ in its decimal expansion. Prove that there exists a natural number $ k $, such that
$$ \underbrace { S \bigg( S \Big( S \big( \dots S } _ { k \text { times} } ( n ) \big) \dots \Big) \bigg) $$
is a single digit number.

Any help with this proof will be appreciable.

Comment: This process of taking repeated sums of digits is often called "casting out nines".  It results in a single digit which is congruent to $n$ modulo $9$.  Perhaps you've already heard of this in that context?  There have been previous questions about it on the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A pedagogical proof that 9's can be ignored when calculating digital roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221486/a-pedagogical-proof-that-9s-can-be-ignored-when-calculating-digital-roots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n$ has $d$ digits. Then $S(n) \le 9 \, d \,$. For $d \ge 3, 9d \,$ will always have fewer than $d$ digits, i.e. if $n$ has three digits or more, then $S(n)$ will have fewer digits than $n \,$.

Thus the sequence $n, S(n), S(S(n)), S(S(S(n))), \ldots$ must reduce the number of digits at every step until one gets number with less than three digits, call it $N$.

If $N$ is a single-digit number, then we're done. If $N$ is a two-digit number, then $S(N) \le 18$, but then $S(S(N)) \le 9$, and again we're done.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is very easy to see, because $s(n)<n$ unless $n$ is a single digit number. So $s(s(n))>s(n)$ and so on, we get
$s(s(...s(n))...)<...<s(s(n))<s(n)<n$ as long as $s(s(...s(n))...)$ is not a single digit integer.  So if you compose that very many times (enough times), you will reach a single digit number.

To prove $s(n)<n$, simply use the base 10 expansion.